# CMU-Sphinx android build error

Tags: android, cmusphinx

I recently using CMU-Sphinx for Android. When I try to build the sample project from the websites, I got the following error:

> "Compile thumb : pocketsphinx_jni <= pocketsphinx_wrap.c
>
> C:/CMUSphhinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'nbest_s_hyp':
>   C:/CMUSphhinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:793:6: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>   C:/CMUSphhinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'ps_decoder_s_getHyp':
>   C:/CMUSphhinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:847:3: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>   SharedLibrary  : libpocketsphinx_jni.so
>
> C:/CMUSphhinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//obj/local/armeabi/objs/pocketsphinx_jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.o: In function `nbest_s_hyp':
>   C:/CMUSphhinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:793: undefined reference to`new_Hypothesis'
>   C:/CMUSphhinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//obj/local/armeabi/objs/pocketsphinx_jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.o: In function `ps_decoder_s_getHyp':
>   C:/CMUSphhinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:847: undefined reference to`new_Hypothesis'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [C:/CMUSphhinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//obj/local/armeabi/libpocketsphinx_jni.so] Error 1

I am using Windows with these tools:
eclipse Indigo.
android 2.2 sdk
android ndkbuild-r8b
swigwin-2.0.8

and this is my configuration on my eclipse:
SWIG:
Main: C:\swigwin-2.0.8\swig.exe

NDK-build:
Main:
C:\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build.cmd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try swig 1.3. There could be issues with 2.0. Check full build log for details.

Answer (score 0):

pocketsphinx-0.7 is incompatible with the swig-2.0.8

Comment: yes it's true, I tried to compile it with swigwin 1.3, and it works fine